# Get the row number from given indeces in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[4,5,6]}, 
                  index=['first','second','third'])
```

Retrieving the corresponding indeces from a given list of row numbers is simple:

```
df.iloc[[1,2]].index
```

But what about the converse? Suppose I am given a list `['second','third']`. How can I return `df`'s row numbers 0 and 1 from that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df.index.get_indexer(['second', 'third'])
```

Output:

```
array([1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

We have `get_indexer_for` as well

```
df.index.get_indexer_for(['second', 'third'])
Out[178]: array([1, 2], dtype=int32)
```

And for get the value do index slice only is good enough, not need to filter the dataframe

```
df.index[[1,2]]
Out[181]: Index(['second', 'third'], dtype='object')
```